# How to use axis2 (1.8.2) dependency with httpclient5

Tags: java, maven, httpclient, apache-axis

we are upgrading from httpclient4 to httpclient5 in our application but we also use axis2 (1.8.2) dependecy in our application, which internally uses httpclient4. as there is no package conflict in httpclient4 and 5 we have included both of them and it works for us. But is there any way we can remove httpclient4 dependency from our project

Comment: It depends what you need from the axis2 lib. If the parts you use needs the old lib you won't be able to remove it without breaking your code.